# React Native failed to download gradle from distributionUrl

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I am trying to run React native app after setup process using npx react-native run-android.
The application runs to the point of starting up the emulator and gets to the point where it needs to download the gradle from the distributionUrl.
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3-all.zip
Below is the error

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Downloading from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3-all.zip failed: timeout

Comment: I commented in a similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74059225/gradle-connect-timeout did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. Tried searching this issue and there are questions just like yours on GitHub as well with no answer. So I've spent two days finding a workaround to this myself.

This could be either an issue with your internet connection being really slow downloading the zip, or, your internet is blocking the gradle.org download page. For me I had both issues. I rely on using my phones hotspot, which is slow at the moment. And when I used public Wi-Fi, which wasn't slow, I still got the same issue. So I went to gradle.org to download the zip directly. Turns out its blocked. So, I used a VPN and was able to download the zip that way.

Now, knowing I can download the zip directly from the browser with VPN, I've attempted to run android build and see if it would download the Gradle zip this time. Turns out, failed again, with a "Connection reset" error. Okay easy, so I've tried building again. Now I get an error like this: "No subject alternative DNS name matching services.gradle.org found.".

So, I came to conclusion that I just wasn't able to download the zip from the build as it has been repeatedly doing so on every build attempt, even though I already had my gradle zip downloaded and set up with environmental variables BEFORE I encountered this issue in the first place. This is where I begin to form my workaround to this.

SOLUTION 1:

The first solution to this error would be to do as follow:

1. In your android project at the very beginning of your project, go to gradle > gradle.wrapper.properties.
2. Change this:

> > > distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-[YOUR_GRADLE_VERSION]-all.zip

To this:

> > > distributionUrl=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-[YOUR_GRADLE_VERSION]-all.zip
> > > 3. Then, run build android

SOLUTION 2:

The first solution which I've got from other sources did not work for me.
So my solution, the second solution, to this is my step by step workaround:

1. Looking at the error you got when running an android build, it shows the link to the gradle zip it is attempting to download. Look for the gradle version on that link, and remember it. (In your case it would be 7.3)
2. Open up your browser and search "gradle install". Look for the search result with "install" and make sure its from "gradle.org".
3. Download the gradle-all version that you,ve seen from step 1. Make sure to pick the "Complete" option for download, and not "Binary-only". Then your download will result in a "gradle-all.zip".
4. Open your file explorer, locate to "C:\Users[YOUR_USERNAME].gradle\wrapper\dists". Now, because you've attempted to run android, you should see a "gradle-[VERSION]-all" folder for the version your react native project is trying to download. Ignore the other gradle folders if you have multiple. Open that specific folder, and you should see another folder named with some sort of key of random numbers and letters. If you have more than one, delete them all, rerun android build, then come back. Either way, once you are left with one folder, open it.
5. There should be no gradle folders inside this folder. If you see one, remove them. All you should see are a couple files, one being a .lck file.
6. Open a new file explorer window and locate the gradle-all.zip that you downloaded earlier in your downloads. Drag it into the previous file explorer window into the folder.
7. Exit. Now re-run android build

I really hope my solution worked for you as there were really no solutions that I could find myself. Let me know and I may as well take this one down. I will also post a video somewhere for clearer explanation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).